# Why does ckeditor plugin tab doesn't work?

Tags: tabs, ckeditor

Hy,

I need the tab function to work in Ckeditor and I put the "tab" plugin in the plugin folder and I told the editor but when I press tab on the keyboard the focus leaves the editor. What am I doing wrong? My script:

```
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { 
                width: 795, height: 642,
                enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV,
                shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
            }
            );
            CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
                config.toolbarGroups = [
                    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
                    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
                    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
                    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
                    '/',
                    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
                    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
                    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
                    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
                    '/',
                    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
                    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
                    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
                    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
                    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
                ];

                config.removeButtons = 'Source,Save,Templates,NewPage,Preview,Print,Flash,HorizontalRule,Smiley,PageBreak,Iframe,ShowBlocks,Maximize,About,Link,Unlink,Anchor,Language,CreateDiv';
                config.extraPlugins = 'tab';    };

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to move the text when pressing tab, you need to set the `tabSpaces` configuration setting to value greater than `0` e.g.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    tabSpaces : 4
});
```

Please also see:https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-tabSpaces

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but it's only works to the first line. When I press Tab, the focus get out of the document.